# Using Streaming in WSO2 DSS for large response

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to invoke a WSO2 DSS service inside a WSO2 ESB call mediator which would return 1000 rows comprising of a very large XML (per row). I don't want this to crash my ESB. Hence, I would like to pass the row into my ESB call mediator one by one.

But, I don't want to continuously invoke the DSS service returning one row at a time (ESB call mediator within an Iterator) as this would cause an over-head to my database.

I heard that this could be achieved by using **streaming** in DSS service.
But I could not understand on how streaming works in DSS and how this can be implemented inside an ESB.

Please help !!
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

By default, we have enabled streaming for all the data sources you create with WSO2 Data Services Server. Hence, you don't need to do anything to enable streaming in your data sources. For details, please find the attached screenshot.

[image]

So you should be able to call data services service inside the call mediator without any performance penalty.

If you need further help regarding this issue please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I do know that the streaming is added by default, but my question is, Is it possible to control the streaming. 

My scenario is , I will get a large xml with one root and multiple children (very huge xml per child) from my DSS server. I want to iterate through the children one at a time.

I wanted to know whether is it possible to get the response from DSS as one child at a time. Because getting the entire response from DSS at once will crash my WSO2 ESB I believe.

Kindly Suggest me if it is possible.

Comment: @Aswin presently,  very fine-grained streaming (such as one described you) does not support in DSS.